# Запятая перед "я"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*В течение твоего обучения(,) я выдам тебе всего 6 уроков.*

Нужна ли тут запятая перед "я"?

Comment: Уроки теперь выдают? Всего по шесть в одни руки?

Comment: Трудно себе представить предложение с обособленным оборотом для предлогом  "в течение". Обособление же любого оборота никак не связано с личным местоимением (это только тема обособленных определений).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрим, что говорят авторитеты.

> Розенталь:
> **2.** Чаще всего обособленные обстоятельственные конструкции образуются существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями: ***благодаря, ввиду, в зависимости, во избежание, вопреки, в отличие, в противоположность, в связи с, в силу, вследствие, в случае, за неимением, за отсутствием, несмотря на, подобно, по причине, по случаю, при, при наличии, при условии, согласно*** и др.
>
> Лопатин:
> § 75. <...> Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания).

Обстоятельства с предлогом "в течение" выделяются запятыми нечасто.
Считаю, что в этом предложении не глобально распространенный оборот, стоящий  в начале предложения и не разрывающий основу, имеющий значение "во время твоего обучения", в обособлении не нуждается (то есть запятая перед "я" не нужна).
Не очень хороши здесь повторы (*твоего* и *тебе*) и использование глагола "выдам" (если только это не саркастический контекст).
Я бы написала так:
*В течение всего обучения я дам тебе только 6 уроков.*

Из Нацкорпуса:
*Сегодня уже был в школе. **Дал 6 уроков**. Горло побаливает* (В. Д. Варзацкий. Дневник);
***В течение всего этого бурного двухсотлетия** непрестанно колебалось дело Петра под напором стихии...* (Н. В. Устрялов. Судьба Петербурга);
***В течение всего срока пребывания на этом посту** этот горе-руководитель занят только одним* (Б. А. Макаров. Голос в тумане).

[Обособленные обстоятельства. Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114) (Розенталь)
[Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121) (Лопатин)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, ну можно извратиться и сделать "я выдам тебе..." несогласованной сложносочиненной частью.

-Привет, Лёша, я твой куратор, давай я введу тебя в курс дела.

-А когда мне можно будет сдать кровь, и сколько уроков вы мне *выдадите*?

-В течении твоего обучения, я *выдам* тебе всего 6 уроков...

Answer (score 0):

Нет, тут нет никаких оснований, чтобы ставить запятую. «В течении твоего обучения» просто указывает на время совершения действия.